# Как добавить условие выхода из цикла while

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

while not pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("done_canceling.png", confidence=0.95):
      pyautogui.press('2')
      sleep(1)
print("Все лоты отменены")
```

Пишу кликера для игры. Данный скрипт считывает изображение с экрана и пока на экране не появилось изображение done_canceling.png скрипт нажимает кнопку '2' раз в секунду. Иногда это изображение не появляется на экране и цикл выполняется бесконечно. Как написать условие выхода из цикла например спустя 100 нажатий на кнопку '2' или спустя 2 минуты? Возможно ли это?

Comment: Заводите счетчик и в цикле считаете количество нажатий. Когда счетчик равен 100 - делаете выход. То же со временем - получаете время перед циклом. В цикле проверяете текущее время, если разница составила более 2 минут - выход из цикла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

думаю это решение вам должно помочь

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

counter = 0
while counter < 100 and not pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("done_canceling.png", confidence=0.95):
      pyautogui.press('2')
      sleep(1)
      counter+=1    
print("Все лоты отменены")
```

Comment: @ГерманБорисов да, так правильнее будет. Для меня это новинка, с вашего позволения отредактирую свой ответ

Answer (score 2):

Ещё вариант - считать через цикл `for`, чтобы не писать самому инициализацию, проверку и инкремент счётчика:

```py
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

for counter in range(100):
    if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("done_canceling.png", confidence=0.95):
        break 
    pyautogui.press('2')
    sleep(1)
print("Все лоты отменены")
```

Comment: Вариант Аске чуть лучше, потому что после выхода можно понять, что мы вышли по тайауту.